# Which tool should be used to record user actions/inputs to use them later on with cypress

Tags: node.js, action, user-input, node-modules, cypress

Which tool should I use to record user actions/inputs to use them later on with cypress or does cypress has that kind of tool?

Comment: I don't think Cypress has a recording functionality available.

Comment: yea, i just started to try "uirecorder". thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypress does not have a record "user actions" feature. There is an issue open for this [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/73).

Cypress recently released a [CSS Selector Playground](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/917#issuecomment-352226169) to aid in getting selectors manually while developing.

Comment: Yes, I was watching that proposal. I know you are a member of the developer team of cypress. so my question is that is there any plan to implement "user actions" feature?

Answer (score -1):

Your can it up to video record your run in the cypress dashboard. It used to be default for it to record a video but this seems to have changed. If you are cypress through the command line you just need to add a '--record' flag.Instructions for how to do it from the dashboard are here : [Recording through dashboard Instructions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/dashboard-service.html#Setup)